# How did this apparatus actually work - discovery of induced nuclear fission?

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, history, particle-detectors

Despite all the ugliness threaded through this story, I'd like to understand the physics of this apparatus of Otto Hahn, Lise Meitner and Fritz Strassmann (in alphabetical order). The system shown represents the first measurement of fission induced by neutron radiation.

**note:** While this [NYTimes Obituary of Otto Hahn](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/projects/cp/obituaries/archives/otto-hahn) does not explain it - the link in the answer below does.

It looks like the electronics in the back might be a power supply, and the two identical electronic systems on the left and right could be amplifiers - is it somehow detecting coincidences of both fission fragments? The boxes labeled `PERTRIX` seem to be [90V batteries used in many radios in the 1930s](http://www.radiomuseum.org/dsp_hersteller_detail.cfm?company_id=7709). The fact that there are so many more in series on the shelf below suggests a [Geiger–Müller tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93M%C3%BCller_tube) or at least some kind of [gas ionization detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaseous_ionization_detectors), but I don't see any in the photo.

**Question:** How did this thing work?

[image]

**Above:** Image from the [NYTimes Obituary](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/projects/cp/obituaries/archives/otto-hahn) credited there to *Hulton Archive/Getty Images*.

Comment: Would [hsm.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: That said, have you tried looking at Hahn, Strassmann and Meitner's papers describing their work?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty it's a good question - I'm hoping to have an answer that explains the physics behind how this actually worked. Is there a coincidence circuit? Is there a counter? I've asked a [related question in HSM](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/5067/3869) as well. I don't have access to those papers, ant it may take a while for me to understand them. So I'm asking here.

Comment: I'd like to direct all readers' attention to [*The Making of the Atomic Bomb*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Making_of_the_Atomic_Bomb), by Rhodes. It is essentially a history of nuclear physics from the late 1800's through the development of atomic bombs. The apparatus pictured in this post, as well as the work and relationships of Otto Hahn, Lise Meitner, and all other notable physicists of that era is discussed in some detail. The author provides political and historical context surrounding the research.

Comment: The thing near the top-center looks like an electromechanical counter (maybe a pair of them) that moves an indicator needle across a ruled card in response to a "click" from the G-M tube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is discussed briefly [in this article on the IAEA website](https://www.iaea.org/newscenter/news/pioneering-nuclear-science-discovery-nuclear-fission).

The apparatus shown was for measuring the radioactivity from a sample of uranium that had been irradiated with neutrons. The irradiation was done separately, then the treated samples had their emission measured with the kit above. Finally the samples were analysed in a chemical lab to identify the elements present.

The radiation from uranium is constant on lab timescales, but the equipment shown above was able to measure changes in emission due to decay of the short lived fission products. This showed the uranium had been transformed into some other element(s). The chemical analysis was able to identify one of the new elements as barium.

Comment: OK - the short lived activity of the fission products induced by neutron irradiation immediately before (and at a separate location). That's a helpful answer! I'm hoping that someone can actually identify the circuits/objects there. Did this make 'clicks' that were manually counted(?), or an elevated average current in the detectors read out on a meter(?), things like that.

Comment: @uhoh: some of this is obvious. GM tubes were used (as the article says) and the sample cells are the lead blocks at the front of the table - the one on the right is open. The circuits in the middle are presumably amplifiers to drive the GM tubes and detect the signal. Note that there are two detection rigs on the table. However I cannot find any info on how the final output was displayed.

Comment: Well there are a lot of questions here to which the answer is obvious to some, and totally not obvious to others, and the totally wrong answer is obvious to others still. I'm going to assume there are two because there's only room for two detectors for practical reasons. OK the linked article is really helpful, and there's no need to regenerate it here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

At the suggestion of uhoh, I am reproducing a response I posted  on History of Science and Mathematics site[image]

The above photo was reproduced in the biography: Lise Meitner, A life in Physics, by Ruth Lewin Sime; University Of California Press,1996, ISBN 0-520-20860-9. A brief description of the parts is given on page 371, bottom and 372 top. The attached photo, describing some of the components, is from those included with the text. Lise Meitner's apparatus

Comment: Thank you - [your answer](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/5087/3869) in History of Science and Mathematics SE was helpful to me here as well - getting the attribution of the experimental apparatus correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty good [explainer image from the Nuclear Fission Deutsches Museum](https://www.flickr.com/photos/brewbooks/176055954).
This grouping was divided across 3 rooms for the actual 1938 experiment.

[image: Induced fission expt]

Comment: Hello @StellaD, and welcome to Stack Exchange! Thank you for contributing an answer and link. What a cool Flikr site, I will enjoy browsing it! Since this is your first post in SE, I'll explain a little more that a good SE answer should contain more than a link to the answer. Links break over time, and the value of a link-only answer is lost. If you can add a little more that would be great! I can see JohnRennie has already added an image with some of the explanation.